# Self-Hosting TFS PackageManagement (nuget server)

Tags: tfs, nuget, nuget-server, package-management

I was interested in exploring the new PackageManagement service for TFS/Team Services -- though at a glance, it doesn't look like there's a self-hosted option for on-prem TFS server.

Can anyone confirm?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no on-prem/private Package Management option for VSTS (i.e. no hybrid approach where you use hosted VSTS and private Package Management)

Also for on-prem, it's available for TFS2017+ only...

[Package Management is generally available: NuGet, npm, and more](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/11/16/package-management-ga-nuget-npm-more/)

> "Today, I’m proud to announce that Package Management is generally
>   available for Team Services and **TFS 2017**! If you haven’t already,
>   install it from the Visual Studio Marketplace...."